# Firefox 19: Erratic frame rate using requestAnimationFrame and HTML5 canvas. FPS is over 60

Tags: html, firefox, canvas, frame-rate, requestanimationframe

I am developing a game using HTML5 canvas, so I have the game loop that I call using requestAnimationFrame. When I use Chrome or IE it works fine, steady 60 fps and smooth as it should. Issues start when I run it on Firefox. FPS counter goes above 60 fps (it sets around 65-70) and the playing experience doesn't feel smooth at all. If it actually runs over 60 fps I suppose I might be losing some frames. this is the code I'm using for the game loop:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60); 
    };
})();

    gameloop=function(){
       //Here I do my calculations and drawings

       //I do this to calculate FPS
       thisLoop=new Date;
       var fps=1000/(thisLoop-lastLoop);
       lastLoop=thisLoop;

       requestAnimFrame(gameloop());
    }
```

Do you have an explanation for this? This might even be normal but I play other games and they don't seem to behave like this at all on firefox.

I tried this solution:

http://my.opera.com/emoller/blog/2011/12/20/requestanimationframe-for-smart-er-animating

but the end result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
requestAnimationFrame(gameloop());
```

Is that right?  That would mean you're calling the game loop from itself and waiting for it to finish (which will never happen) before passing its return value (`null`) to `requestAnimationFrame`.  Your game would run as fast as possible and never yield to the UI.

Comment: I just edited it. 

Where it said: requestAnimationFrame(gameloop());
it is, calling the shown function: requestAnimFrame(gameloop());

Comment: Yes, I call the game loop from itself. That should be fine as long as everybody uses it.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` accepts a function to be called _later_.  you're calling the function (immediately) instead of passing it.  try removing the parentheses.

Comment: That was a good point! Still having some performance problems though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`requestAnimFrame(gameloop());`

Here is your error, this is not a callback, you are just calling the method outright.

`requestAnimFrame(gameloop);`

This sends `requestAnimationFrame` the actual gameloop function to call.

Answer (score 0):

SO has some question postings about [FPS and `requestAnimationFrame`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73557825/frame-rate-reported-by-requestanimationframe-is-sometimes-higher-than-the-displa).

But, if you read, to think about this issue, the code should be improved. It looks weird in learning/debugging hubs, and a problem is in `requestAnimFrame(gameloop())` where it has to be `requestAnimFrame(gameloop)`!